# Get the host IP from my django app container

Tags: django, nginx, docker

There is a feature on our web app that we need to send the IP of our server but I always send `172.17.0.2` because that is the value of  `request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']` which is usually `127.0.0.1` when using django in localhost and which I assume is the TCP address of our NGINX container which where the request is coming from. **How will I send the IP of my docker host instead?**

Containers:

- Nginx
- Django with gunicorn
- PostgreSQL
- Redis

Comment: Are you just wanting your public IP address?  It's unclear.

Comment: Sorry, didn't pay attention to the docker host part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass it as an environment variable to your container when you create it. Then, read that environment variable in your Django code.

You can do it with option `-e HOST_IP=$(/sbin/ip route | awk '/default/ { print $3 }')` in `docker run` command.

In `docker-compose.yml`, you could do something like this.

```
django:
  environment:
    - HOST_IP=$(/sbin/ip route | awk '/default/ { print $3 }')
```

Comment: How can I do that when I use a `.env` file to store my environment varibles?

Comment: So how can I do that inside my .env? I'm using docker-compose.yml. I'm actually looking for something automated not run on a manual like that.. sorry..

Comment: I've just added an example of how this would be done in docker-compose.yml.

Comment: Wow, might as well try this one

Comment: ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "environment" option in service "celery": "HOST_IP=$(/sbin/ip route | awk '/default/ { print $3 }')"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import subprocess
host = subprocess.check_output(['bash', '-c', "/sbin/ip route|awk '/default/ { print $3 }'"]).decode('utf-8').strip()
```

Comment: It returned `172.17.0.1`

Comment: Is your host container behind a NAT?  172.17.0.1 is a NAT address.  If you want to get the public URL of the server, that is something different.

Comment: Most probably yes, my container's network is on the default which is `bridge`

Comment: If you are needing your public IP, you may have to use an external source, like from from ipify.org.  It looks like you have accepted the other answer though, so I guess that worked.

Comment: To be honest ipify was my primary solution for this, I just want to know other methods. But thanks a lot for your answer and comments!